# How to classify a continuous Raster using Mapinfo

Tags: raster, mapinfo

I have a continuous raster and i want to classify it into a raster with 10 classes. So the min and max of the raster is suppose 0-100. I want to create 10 classes like 0-10, 10-20.....90-100. How to do that in Mapinfo?

I have heard that Mapinfo has added new Raster capabilities. 
So if someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have MapInfo Pro Advanced, v15.2 or newer, you can use the Classify Raster Processing tool to create a new classified raster from your continouos raster.

You select the input raster, specify the intervals/classes and specify the name and type of the output raster file.

There is an article here in the LI360 Forum which will take you thru the process step by step: [Raster - Classifying a raster into bands or ranges](https://li360.pitneybowes.com/s/article/ka1800000004b2lAAA/Raster-Classifying-a-raster-into-bands-or-ranges)